# How do i convert .dwg to .dxf with free software?

Tags: software-recommendation, cad

How do i convert .dwg to .dxf using free software(as in freedom) only (webapps are ok) ?

Comment: @Rinzind that is for viewing whereas this is for converting so i can use .dxf files in qcad or FreeCad .

Answer (score 8):

## [ODA File Converter](http://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/teighafileconverter)

(Formerly known as Teigha File Converter)

This is 'free as in beer' software however I have no other alternative.

There is a DEB package for installing on Ubuntu 32-bit.

However, for Ubuntu 64-bit users, like myself, you are relegated to downloading the Windows installer and using Wine to install it. Note that you will need Wine version >= 1.3.5 otherwise MSVC++2010 installer crashes.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the type of free software. I think limiting this question to only libre software is too narrow for the topic so you should allow some leeway for other suggestions.

Comment: If you think this question is too narrow and think AskUbuntu should have information about non-free software that converts .dwg to .dxf, you can [ask and answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) about that, and post a comment in this question linking to it. This answer, as it stands, does not actually attempt to answer the question that the OP asked.

Comment: On Teigha site they have included 64-bit deb file, but of poor quality. Do you have any experience with it?

Comment: I have installed Teigha Viewer in many Ubuntus, and it always crashed when trying to open any DWG file. Do you have any advice to make it work?

Comment: I created the following question to try to solve the problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018121/teigha-viewer-for-dwg-files-how-to-install-and-make-it-work-properly

Answer (score 3):

There is [Draftsight](http://www.3ds.com/products/draftsight/download-draftsight/), currently in beta on Ubuntu.
I've used it on Windows and it look pretty good for a free (of cost) app

Comment: Why the -1? DraftSight has a free version that allows conversions of that kind

Answer (score 1):

Just use Autocad's webapp:

https://app.autocad360.com

Upload your .dwg (you can even view or edit) then download as .dxf.

Comment: It seems that this is no longer possible in 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried the following myself. Just searched some.

- [DWG to DXF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lx-viewer/files/DWG%20to%20DXF/). Seems to be a terminal program.
- [LX-Viewer](http://lx-viewer.sourceforge.net/). I found this via [Open Source DWG to DXF Converter?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/open-source-dwg-to-dxf-converter-431197/) Seems to have a GUI.

Comment: it cannot convert the files from newer versions of autocad and it's last revision was in 2002.