# ODA Drawings Explorer (formerly Teigha Viewer) for DWG files. How to install and make it work properly?

Tags: qt, qt5, cad

ODA Drawings Explorer (formerly Teigha Viewer) is a free (not libre) viewer for proprietary DWG files, developed by Open Design Alliance.

The developing company provides RPM and DEB packages for easy installation at [their site](https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/teigha_viewer).

I download the 64 bit DEB package, and install it using:

```
sudo dpkg -i TeighaViewer_QT5_lnxX64_4.7dll.deb
```

After that, the software is easily installed and I can run the software from Dash (windows key + typing Teigha) or from bash with the command

```
TeighaViewer
```

The software loads quickly and automatically prompts to open a file. This is where the trouble beings... and ends: **the moment I select any DWG, TeighaViewer consistently crashes every time**.

- Regardless if I select big or small DWGs
- Regardless of the location of the files I select or permissions.
- Regardless if the DWG file was generated with a new or old version of AutoCAD
- Regardless if I install the Windows version of Teigha with wine and run it

In all of these cases, Teigha systematically crashes.

I have even tried to open the DWG file directly from command line by issuing:

```
TeighaViewer myTestFile.dwg
```

But it still crashes. Note there are no spaces in the name of test DWG file being opened.

When running Teigha from command line, there is a hint of the problem though:

```
~$ TeighaViewer myTestFile.dwg 
QString::arg: Argument missing: Property Dialog, Teigha Viewer
QString::arg: Argument missing: Property Dialog, Teigha Viewer
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'OdError'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have googled everywhere for these errors, and came empty handed.

Could the be related to missing QT libraries?

---

**My setup:**

```
$ lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10

$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.26.2

$ uname -a
Linux 4.13.0-36-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 16 20:07:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep model
model       : 142
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
```

---

If anyone was able to make TeighaViewer run on Ubuntu, I would like to know their setup (Ubuntu version, 32 or 64 bit, graphics card in use)

Comment: Make sure all dependencies were installed. Run `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: Use this simple draw https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/raw/master/tests/testdata/dwg/entities.dwg

Comment: There certainly seems to be something wrong with the installer on that application because when I tried, it couldn't even find its own shared objects. As a possible alternative, there is a DWG application available from 3DS for Ubuntu (although its still in beta) and it is available [here](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/free-download/). I've tried it in the past and it seemed to work well.

Comment: @estibordo Nothing else is installed with that command. System is 100% up to date. The test DWG file also crashes Teigha upon loading. Does this indicate anything in particular?

Answer (score 3):

### [ODA Drawings Explorer](https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/oda_drawings_explorer)

To install *ODA Drawings Explorer* (formerly known as *Teigha Viewer*, freeware but not free nor open source software):

1. Download [ODA Drawings Explorer](https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/oda_drawings_explorer) for Linux 64-bit (DEB) manually or using commands below:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   wget -c https://download.opendesign.com/guestfiles/Demo/ODADrawingsExplorer_QT5_lnxX64_7.2dll_22.6.deb
   ```
2. Install the dependency and then the downloaded DEB package

   ```
   sudo apt install qt5-default
   sudo apt install ./ODADrawingsExplorer_QT5_lnxX64_7.2dll_22.6.deb
   ```

This will install `odadrawingsexplorer` package and `/usr/bin/ODADrawingsExplorer` GUI app.

[image: screenshot]

### [ODA File Converter](https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/oda_file_converter)

For *ODA File Converter* ([formerly known](https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/FreeCAD_and_DWG_Import) as *Teigha File Converter*):

1. Download [ODA File Converter](https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/oda_file_converter) for Linux 64-bit (DEB) manually or using commands below:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   wget -c https://download.opendesign.com/guestfiles/Demo/ODAFileConverter_QT5_lnxX64_7.2dll_22.6.deb
   ```
2. Install the package

   ```
   sudo apt install ./ODAFileConverter_QT5_lnxX64_7.2dll_22.6.deb
   ```

Same as above but with it will install `odafileconverter` and `/usr/bin/ODAFileConverter` GUI app.

### DWG converter on FreeCAD

To install and [add the DWG converter to FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/index.php?title=Dxf_Importer_Install#Third_step:) use latest stable FreeCAD from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Efreecad-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/freecad-stable).

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable # An older version without PPA
sudo apt install freecad
```

It's also available [on Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.freecadweb.FreeCAD) ([related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1384366/349837)).

```sh
flatpak install flathub org.freecadweb.FreeCAD
```

[image: screenshot]

Note: the `qt5-default` package is not available for Ubuntu 21.04, you have to use some [workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/1335187/66509). To get Qt 5.14 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS you can use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1355575/66509).